# When to use an SQL clause of WHERE c.column = null?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I spent quite a bit of time understanding the mismatch of a language that supports nulls and SQL standards where c.col = null returns 0 rows even if c.col has rows with null in it.  I began to wonder in what use cases would someone want to do c.col = null in a where clause in SQL.

I do clearly get that currently if I do WHERE c.col is null, I get back rows where c.col contains a null.  This begs the question though, there must be a use and reason for c.col = null to have differing behavior.  It must be used by someone, right?  I am then curious the context of when we do that?

(I see tons of confusion on SO where people --including me-- thought that in SQL WHERE c.col=null would result in all rows that had null in column col).  However, I also realize there is contexts I don't know about and am curious of the context when someone might do c.col = null.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: The SQL standard insists that you cannot use = NULL, or <> NULL, and instead should use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.

Comment: @Abra First, thanks, you are way  closer to answering my question then the answer below.   So, next, why does the SQL standard insist on never using =NULL ?    Is there a blog on the reasoning behind this decision?   Why not just alleviate a ton of confusion and define = null to be same as is null or does that some how cause confusion with another crowd?

Comment: The "duplicate" question explains why the SQL standard insists on `is null` and not `= null`. Did you read it? Alternatively, see https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/the-null-mistake-and-other-sql-null-heresies

Comment: yeah, I read that too @Abra but it doesn't explain why we don't 'fail' on = null which is probably my last question I guess.  You say the spec says you can't use it so why don't databases just fail it(or at least add an option so it fails all of those).  Of course, if it's not in use, why not just re-define it to mean what many are expecting/want....well, that would probably be a tough sell as many are about sticking with theory instead of the practicality that would come with = null I guess.  oh well.  Still curious why not fail?  At any rate, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` is a special value that signifies no value. Comparing a column to NULL using the `=` operator is undefined.

instead you should use `is` to get the column which has `NULL` value as following

```
select *
from yourTable
where columnName is null
```

for e.g. let's say you have following table `customer` and you want to find names NOT referred by the person with referee_id `2`.

```
| name | referee_id|
+------+-----------+
| Will |      NULL |
| Jane |      NULL |
| Alex |         2 |
| Bill |      NULL |
| Zack |         1 |
| Mark |         2 |
```

your expected output should be

```
| name |
+------+
| Will |
| Jane |
| Bill |
| Zack |
```

to get your output correct you also need to consider referee_id with `NULL` values, so your quesry should be

```
select
    name
from customer
where referee_id <> 2
or referee_id is null
```

Comment: sorry, this does not answer my question.  I already know about is null.  What I don't get is what = null is good for?  If it's good for nothing, it should outright fail to let people know.  When would I se c.col = null ?